# npm installation issues

Tags: express, npm

I have installed express, fs and couple of packages.
when I do

```
npm ls
```

I am getting the following Error:

```
â   âââ mime@1.2.6
âââ fs@0.0.0 extraneous
âââ node-uuid@1.4.0

npm ERR! extraneous: fs@0.0.0 /home/user123/trail/node_modules/fs
npm ERR! extraneous: express@3.0.5 /home/user123/trail/node_modules/express
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am not sure how to get this ERR out?
I am able to run my sample application using the azure and express.
not sure if it is taking from sudo npm ? if so how.
I want to know when will it take from sudo npm list (global)? and when from npm list (locally).

```
sudo npm ls
```

there are no Errors

Comment: How did you install express?

Comment: It looks like you have been manually putting things inside the node_modules folder.

Comment: I did not keep anything manually. use npm install express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm prune should take care of it. 
Except it deletes the dependecy after the fact. And that might not be what you want to do.

In case you need the dependency, declare it in package.json like this:

...
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.5"
},
...

Also note that dependency 'fs' is part of node and there is no need to declare in package.json explicitly.